# Debug GRAILS 3 in eclipse

Tags: grails

I would like to know if is there any way to debug a Grails 3 application with a single-click from eclipse (mars) IDE, in the same way as a Java (or Java Spring Boot) web application that it is possible to do a "debug on server".

It is possible to "run as" "gradle build" ... but not a "debug as" "gradle build".

Is there any way for doing this or is there any intention to have this functionality in the future?

Any eclipse plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: However I can run app from  "Java Application" debug configuration and pointing to main method - it's still ignoring my breakpoints in controllers or services... How to debug it properly?

Comment: Moreover attaching remote debugger via `gradle bootRun --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true` and "Remote Java Application" debug configuration is not detecting my breakpoints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found working solution. My eclipse IDE version:

> Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
>
> Build id: 20160218-0600

Installation details -> Installed software:

```
Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle  1.0.11.v20160328-1759   org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  4.5.2.20160218-0600 epp.package.jee null
Groovy Compiler 2.4 Feature 2.9.2.xx-201603042130-e45   org.codehaus.groovy24.feature.feature.group Codehaus.org
Groovy-Eclipse Feature  2.9.2.xx-201603042130-e45   org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group   Codehaus.org
Spring IDE Core (required)  3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group   Spring IDE Developers
```

After importing project to workspace add new debug **Spring Boot App** configuration:

[image]

Enjoy debugging.