# Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Problems

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, ggts

Recently I was using Eclipse Luna for GGTS but It was creating problems for Grails 3 or upper version. and in case of lower version it created  error Like this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(GitProfileRepository.groovy:72)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:173)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.getBaseUsage(GrailsCli.groovy:118)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

From Command line while typing grails. I got this:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/Program Files/grails-2.2.4/bin/lib/org.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.3.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

what i want to do I want to configure Eclipse Mars for GGTS with grails version 3 or above. Need suggestions what do?

Comment: Which exactly version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.1.6

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29758784/2166188 (read all answers)

Comment: What about Mars eclipse plugin?

Comment: Better download mars eclipse and use it for develop grails3 apps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36352477/2166188 And do not use spaces in your paths (do not install eclipse or grails in "Program Files") - it may cause further errors.